# What to do when a deal breaker is played against a complete set with more property in it...?

Tags: monopoly-deal

I have a red color property complete set(3 cards) then I put rent and my opponent gives me another red. Then my moves ended. My opponent put a deal breaker now I have to give him a set (3 cards) or all of it(4 cards) .

Comment: What does the deal breaker card say? Providing that information will help get answers as people won't have to research what you are asking as much.

Answer (score 2):

You would have put the new red card in another place -- it doesn't go in the set that's already full (you're starting a new set of red).

When they play Deal Breaker, they only get the full set (3 cards in this case)